# When using equation excel changes number entirely how to fix?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Hello I am trying to concatenate 2 values in excel for example I want madsyo23 and the port 2/4/03 to be concatenate to be madsyo23_2/4/3. When I use my formula it changes it to madsyo23_38018. There are no underlying equation to change it to this arbitrary value. All of the ports are in this format 2/4/03 or 2/4/13 I want to remove all of the leading zeros in the last group of numbers 03 to 3 as well.

The end goal would be to have the concatenation look like madsyo23_2/4/3 or madsyo23_2/4/13

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gl8GH.png)

I already tried to use the text function and concatenate and it would give me the correct format

Comment: What is your column `BS` formatted as?  I can't get the data to mimic your issue on my spreadsheet.  If I format that column as a Date, `d/m/yy`, I can run the formula as in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

What formula did you use? Assuming `madsyo23` is in `A1` and `2/4/03` is in `A2`, you could try

```
=A1&"_"&TEXT(A2,"m/d/yy")
```

Edit: After your comment, try:

```
=A1&"_"&SUBSTITUTE(B1,"0","",LEN(B1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B1,"0","")))
```

[image]

Comment: For the port 2/4/03 i need it to be madsyo23_2/4/3... Its not a date. I owuld be easier to just change the format manually but I have 60,000 rows.

Comment: @learningguy - can you please clarify in your OP? Perhaps some sample data and expected output would help.  Your comment that it becomes `madsyo23_38018` leads me to conclude that Excel is taking `2/4/03` and translating that to a Date format...

Comment: When I use the formula the port value becomes this madsyo23_3818. Im not sure what's making it change.

Comment: @learningguy - Can you please post some sample data? One quick thing, try: `=A1&"_'"&SUBSTITUTE(B1,"0","",LEN(B1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B1,"0","")))`

Comment: Just edited the post. when I the new formula I get MADCLE21_'3818

Comment: @learningguy - Try `=B1&"_"&TEXT(SUBSTITUTE(C1,"0","",LEN(C1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(C1,"0",""))),"m/d/yy")`?  The `3818` in the result you're getting, i'm almost positive, is Excel turning that date into the text representation of a date...

Comment: It has the date format but its not giving me the correct value for the port now MADCLE21_6/14/10 using data sets MADCLE21 and 2/1/04. That was what i was thinking as well with excel converting the port to text